# Autogrow textarea upto a certain height only jquery css

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea, autogrow

I am using jQUERY AUTOGROW FROM HERE

- https://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/

NOW I have many `<textarea>` that uses this plugin
but I want some of my special `<textarea>` to auto grow up to a certain `height` it increases above that the '` must go overflow;

**For example,**

```
textarea-> original height->150px;
           if (keyup){ then autogrow }
           if(height>300px){overflow->auto}
```

How can I accomplish this?

a working example is `facebook 's messaging <textarea>` in https://www.facebook.com/messages/

Comment: I would opt to add a new option to the plugin that specifies a max height.

Comment: how to add this @KevinB i call this autogrow like `$('textarea').autogrow();` but how to specify `max-height`?

Comment: well, the plugin itself would have to be modified. I took a quick shot at it and it didn't work, i'd suggest asking the author for help implementing such an option. You can contact the author through github https://github.com/ultimatedelman/autogrow

Comment: Can u give any other options ? or maybe any other plugin? to make itwork

Answer (score 1):

Change the flow?

```
if (keyup){
    if (height>300) {
        overflow->auto
    } else {
        autogrow
    }
}
```